# Slack Slash command with arguments for jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

How to use the text parameter, there is no clear documentation.

My Curl request will be -  curl -X POST http://jenkins.in/buildByToken/buildWithParameters/build?job=slack&token=1234567qwerty&Variable=hello

How to pass arguments to jenkins job using slash command Slack , let's say if i give /build then I need to pass hello as a parameter.

/build hello

It has a field called text, But how to pass my argument to that text field. There is no option to do so. can anyone help me.

Comment: Did you got any answer from your experiments??